# Linux Debian-derived OS NVMe write speeds capped around 600 mb/s

Tags: linux, ssd, nvme, m.2

Hello I have tried multiple Debian-derived Linux OS (Ubuntu and MX Linux) and all have resulted in the same thing. My [Samsung 970 EVO+ M.2](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/970evoplus/) write speeds are  capped around 600~ , give or take 5%. I have tested on exactly 6 different M.2s all resulting with the same cap. I have checked around and saw something from [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/ssdc/data-center-ssds/Intel_Linux_NVMe_Guide_330602-002.pdf) but following their pdf provided I am still at a loss. If anyone has found a definite solution that would be amazing. I have over five  production computers that would need this immediate fix.

Tested with 3+ different mobos.
Tested with 3+ different cpus

Comment: We need adequate details to find a solution. Please click [edit] and post the make and model(s) of the motherboards and their CPUs. Also please advise if CSM Support is enabled in the BIOS/UEFI Firmware settings, and whether Windows 8/10 mode is set on. Please do not click Add Comment as comments pile up, and new comments push old comments off screen. We need the facts about your configuration(s) in the Question so it can always be seen.

Comment: How *exactly* did you test?